# Application Name not visible when asking for permission in android 6.0 during runtime

Tags: android, android-permissions

I've tried to create a RECORD_AUDIO runtime permission. 
To AndroidManifest I've added:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />`

and
to the activity I've added:

```
 // Requesting Record Permission
private static final int REQUEST_RECORD=3;

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Allow in order to use microphone for recording.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                    REQUEST_RECORD);

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                    REQUEST_RECORD);
        }
    }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0apil.png)

Can anybody point out what's wrong? The permission works perfectly but the dialog doesn't show the Application's name. Why is this happening?

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="My.Spinner.Style" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined">
</style>



<style name="AppTheme.navtheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#03A9F4</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.popupTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
</style>
```

colors.xml

```
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="foreground_material_light">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="abc_primary_text_material_light">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="abc_secondary_text_material_light">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Comment: Post your styles.xml

Comment: post your manifest, what is your app_name and where you have defined?

Comment: I've added styles.xml and colors.xml

Comment: I have my application name defined under manifest as 
`<application
       android:label="@string/app_name">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is either in your theme or in your application name.

Either application name is blank or you have used wrong theme because of that name is not visible.

[image]

you can see that application name is there but it might be restricted by Theme or Textcolor in `Theme`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with my phone theme. As soon as I changed it to System Default everything was alright. But somehow, for some other apps, Permissions were working just fine.

Answer (score -2):

Have you added this line in your code:

```
dialog.setTitle("Record Audio");  //Your Title
```

Comment: Where is `dialog` in OP's question?

Comment: The permissions dialog cannot be customized.